# PySide Qt script doesn't launch from Spyder but works from shell

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, spyder

I have a weird bug in my project that uses PySide for its Qt GUI, and in response I'm trying to test with simpler code that sets up the environment.

Here is the code I am testing with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6906552/130164

When I launch that from my shell (`python test.py`), it works perfectly. However, when I run that script in Spyder, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/Desktop/test/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.
```

If it helps, I also get the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/__init__.py:835: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

**Why does that code work when launched from my shell but not from Spyder?**

---

**Update:** Mata answered that the problem happens because Spyder uses Qt, which makes sense. For now, I've set up execution in Spyder using the "Execute in an external system terminal" option, which doesn't cause errors but doesn't allow debugging, either. **Does Spyder have any built-in workarounds to this?**

Answer (score 2):

As `Spyder` also is a `Qt` application, it starts it's own `QApplication`. In the same process only one `QApplication` can exist, that's why you get the first error.

`Sypder` also uses `matplotlib`, and probably, therfore it already will have imported some of the mentioned modules, so that's why you get the second error.

So when usin it like that, you can't create your own `QApplication` or call `matplotlib.use()`. Or maybe it will work if you wrap these calls in `try`/`except`.

Comment: That's what I suspected would be the issue. Do you know if there are any workarounds built into Spyder? For now, I've set up execution in Spyder using the "Execute in an external system terminal" option, which doesn't cause errors but doesn't allow debugging, either. Perhaps Spyder has some workaround to this?

Comment: I don't know spyder well enough, so besides catching the errors I have no idea.

Comment: It is true that Spyder is running in a Qt application instance, but all of the Python console instances get executed in their own separate processes.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and somewhere on stackoverflow was a solution.

Instead of

```
qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Use

```
qApp = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if qApp is None:
        qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I got the same problem but with functional testing (using Qttest and unittest), your solution fix it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work in Spyder if you try to launch the application into an interactive console because that console is specially configured to import several scientific libraries, automatically `show()` matplotlib figures, and a few other details. Type `scientific` at the Spyder console prompt for more details. The result is effectively that a Qt application event loop is already running there.

To get your application to run inside of Spyder:

1. Make sure Spyder is configured to open external consoles with PySide and not PyQt. This can be set from Tools>Preferences>Console>External modules>Qt-Python bindings library selection.
2. With your script active in the editor, hit `F6` to open the Run Settings dialog. Select the "Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter" radio button instead of executing in the current interactive interpreter. Click `OK`. Now run the script by hitting `F5`. Debug the script by hitting `Ctrl+F5`.

Answer (score 1):

The official Spyder wiki has a page on the subject: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder. The gist of it is:

> **Important Note:** Before running a PyQt application in Spyder, you need to change your Graphics backend to `Automatic`. You can do that by going to
>
> ```
> Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics
> ```
>
> After that, please restart your console kernels or Spyder itself for this change to take effect.

There's [an explantion](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder#an-explanation) at the end:

> The most common problem when running a PyQt application multiple times inside Spyder is that a QApplication instance remains in the namespace of the IPython console kernel after the first run. In other words, when you try to re-run your application, you already have a QApplication instance initialized.
>
> Trying to remove that instance will probably cause your program to get stuck in a blocking while-loop, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285497), and using `sys.exit()` doesn't help since it's the same as trying to exit Python (and hence the IPython console).

A suggested solution is doing something like what [@mata suggsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365013/2988730).