# Proper way to quit/exit a PyQt program

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a script which has a login screen and if the cancel button is pressed, I want to exit the application altogether.  I have tried 3 ways:

1. sys.exit()
2. QApplication.quit()
3. QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

Only number 1 works.  The other two makes the dialog box white and it flashes then hangs and I cannot even switch to other applications.  My code is below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


import csv
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import os

from ci_co_table import *
from login import *

class Ci_Co(QMainWindow):
    """Check in and check out module"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Login(QDialog):
    """User login """
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_login_form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(lambda: self.handle_login(servers=servers))
        servers = {}
        with open('servers.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            server_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in server_reader:
                self.ui.cbo_db_name.addItem(row[1])
                servers[row[1]] = (row[0],row[2])

    def handle_login(self, servers=''):
        global user
        global pword
        global database
        global server
        global bg_colour
        user = self.ui.username.text()
        pword = self.ui.password.text()
        database = self.ui.cbo_db_name.currentText()
        server = servers[database][0]
        bg_colour = servers[database][1]


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    global hotdate
    global hotdate_string
    global folio_num
    global user
    global pword
    global dbase
    global server
    pword = ""
    global database
    global bg_colour
    #Login
    while True:
        if Login().exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
            db.setHostName(server)
            db.setDatabaseName(database);
            db.setUserName(user);
            db.setPassword(pword)
            if (db.open()==False):     
                QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())
            else:
                break
        else:
            #QApplication.quit()
            QCoreApplication.instance().quit()            
            #sys.exit()


    myapp = Ci_Co()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Calling `QCoreApplication.quit()` is the same as calling `QCoreApplication.exit(0)`. To quote from the [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit):

> After this function has been called, the application leaves the main
>   event loop and returns from the call to exec(). The exec() function
>   returns *returnCode*. **If the event loop is not running, this function
>   does nothing**. [emphasis added]

So `quit()` or `exit()` are nothing like `sys.exit()`. The latter will terminate the program, but the former will merely terminate the event-loop (if it's running).

When the user cancels the login dialog, your example should just call `sys.exit()` to terminate the program. Otherwise, your program will just get stuck in the blocking while-loop.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `QApplication.quit()`, since you defined `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`, you could just write `app.quit()`, and that should work!

Something unrelated but might be helpful: I think it would be easier if you put the login check at the beginning of the `__init__` function of your `Ci_Co` class. That way, you will start `Ci_Co` at the beginning, but it will first spawn the `Login` class. If the login fails, you can call `app.quit()`, and if it succeeds, it will automatically transition into `Ci_Co`. This saves you from a lot of the things you have to write in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause. Please comment if you have any more questions, I have a similar project with a login dialog box.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about using app.quit().  However, it gives me the same freeze on the dialog box on Windows 10.  I ran the program on Linux Mint and it froze the GUI but I was able to log into a terminal and found that the CPU was at 100% so it seems to be in some kind of loop.  So, app..quit() doesn't behave any differently.

Comment: I see your second point and will consider it the next time I refactor.

Comment: what about sys.exit()?

Answer (score 3):

i try this 3 method to close my `MainWindow()` but it didn't work for my code.

1. sys.exit()
2. QApplication.quit()
3. qApp.quite()

So i use `self.close()` method which work Completely fine with my code.

here is my code

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
        self.ui.QPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.shutprocess())
    
    def shutprocess(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Window Close', 'Are you sure you want to close the window?', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.close()
            print('Window closed')
        else:
            pass
```