# Error getting PySide to work with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pyside

I am trying to make PySide work with matplotlib, and I have the same problem 
described in this thread 
[Getting PySide to work with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723527/getting-pyside-to-work-with-matplotlib)

trying to launch the PySide + matplotlib example from 
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/PySide

I have got an error

```
        win.setCentralWidget(canvas)
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget)
```

Adding of

```
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
```

did not help as well as

```
os.environ["QT_API"] = "pyside"
```

At the same time PyQt4 examples work. 
I use Windows 7, and WinPython 2.7.5.1 (Python 2.7.5, PySide 1.1.2, matplotlib 1.2.1)

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Spyder. 
Everything works in other python dev enviroments.

Jed post the solution on another thread just the next day after my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17376655/2531821