# FigureCanvasQTAgg can't be added as a QWidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to make a simple Qt application using PySide6. In short, it should open the main window, take some data from QLineEdit and plot a matplotlib graph using this data. First of all I tried to make just a Qt window for the qtagg canvas:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvas

fig, ax =  plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
if QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication.instance()
else:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class PlottingWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plotting_window = PlottingWindow()
        widget = QWidget(parent=self)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        
        self.start_button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.show_plotting_window)

    def show_plotting_window(self):
        #some value checking code that is not related to the problem
        self.plotting_window.show()
        return True

main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec()
```

However, it refuses to work:

```
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0, PySide6.QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag = Default(Qt.Alignment))
```

I've googled and found [FigureCanvas not interpreted as QtWidget after using PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182256/figurecanvas-not-interpreted-as-qtwidget-after-using-pyinstaller) topic, but installing and re-installing matplotlib and other recommendations changed nothing. I've also tried to replace backend_qtagg to backend_qt5agg (nothing changed), and to replace pyside6 to pyqt6 (the same error) and to pyside2:

> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, webgl, windows

I just can't understand what can be wrong.

IDE: Spyder 5. Python: Python 3.9. Qt: v.6.6.1

Comment: Try by moving the `plt.subplots` line *after* creating the QApplication instance (you should do that anyway).

Comment: Still doesn't work, the same error

Comment: Also add `from PyQt5 import QtCore` **before** importing matplotlib.

Comment: PyQt5 import produces the same error as the PySide2

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong line by mistake, I obviously meant `from PySide6 import QtCore`.

Comment: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg)'... I reckon, the problem is that matplotlib tells lie in its documentation (which says that it works with Pyside6) and some wrappers of Matplotlib doesn't work correctly with Qt6. But I can't go back to Qt5 because the app refuses to work. Is there any way to fix it? Maybe, delete pyside6 and clean... anything? Or, I have the QtCreator installed (but the code in the topic was written manually), maybe, it causes problems?

Comment: Assuming that matplotlib "tells lie" because you have issues is a bit presumptuous. It's quite more likely that you have a broken configuration or there may be some bug that affects a specific version of PySide or Python. Add the following *right after* the PySide imports: `from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QT_API` and report the output of `print(QT_API)`. Then, consider cleaning up both PySide *and* matplotlib and then reinstall them, and ensure that you're following the correct procedure: I've never used spyder, but I know it and its packages must be properly configured/installed.

Comment: The QT_API value is PyQt5. While I can't import PyQt5 because it causes "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized..." and I have (I've also checked) the last (3.8.2) Matplotlib version. Funny. OK, I'll try to reinstall both libraries (and just in case uninstall for a while QtCreator). P.S. - sorry for my English, I agree that it's quite a poor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256850/discussion-between-agapito-nev-and-musicamante).

Comment: Ok, I completely forgot that Spyder normally runs script in its own process, and since, by default, it uses PyQt, you cannot use PySide within it (they cannot be used together), unless you configure it to use an external interpreter and (as far as I understand) disable its graphics backend. If you run the code in a standard terminal/prompt, it will probably work. Note that the PyQt QApplication issues are probably caused by the fact that you installed PyQt through pip, instead of using conda. I recommend to carefully study the documentation and check [their videos](//youtu.be/Ul79ihg41Rs).